# In post-command-hook, this-command for kill-word has turned into kill-region somehow

Tags: emacs, elisp

In my `post-command-hook` callback, when I do `kill-word`, the `this-command` var is `kill-region` - and not `kill-word` as expected.

I guess that's because `kill-word` uses `kill-region`, but knowing exactly which command was used is essential to my script. Any way to get at that information somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out all the kill-commands change `this-command` to `kill-region` so they can interoperate on appending things to the kill ring. To get to the actual command, emacs has `this-original-command` - which is not modified.