# (basic) Elisp programming: Special hook for Cut function in Emacs

Tags: elisp

I have a text file which has related content/paragraphs in it. Let's say that I Cut/Kill paragraph A from the text. I want to write a function that is invoked in this case and therefore the related paragraph - let's say B - is also removed. A good example would be a document that has citations/references in it. - i.e. whenever you remove that text the citation is also removed - something like what MS Office does. Theoretically I think:

1) I need a hook for Cut - which I can't find the appropriate hook so far
2) A search function with regex probably - to find the related text
3) remove that text

Can you advice me how to proceed? Hints for each step or etc.

Comment: This question has some promising hints for hooking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983758/in-post-command-hook-this-command-for-kill-word-has-turned-into-kill-region-som

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to write functions for such cases:

```
(defun when-one-kill-one-and-three ()
  "If a buffer has a string \"one\", it deletes it.
If in this buffer exists also a string \"three\", it will be killed afterwards. "
  (interactive "*")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward "one" nil t 1)
        (kill-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
        (when (search-forward "three")
          (kill-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't think there is a hook for Cut but you can have advised Cutting (defadvice ..)

2) You should somehow markup your text and find it with search (put a number so you search for that) ..

3) To remove text you can use kill-region I suppose